# Странное поведение виртуальной памяти на Win7 x64 Ultima

Tags: windows-7, администрирование

Доброго дня всем.
Как такое может быть?
ОСь Win7 x64 Макс (4Гб ОЗУ).
Выставляю виртуалку "Указать размер" + "Задать" на 4096Мб.
А винда всё равно пишет 714мб.
и своп-файл в системе тоже 714 мб.
Что-то я ни чего в 7-ке не понимаю.Почему здесь так?
Как мне задать, размер своп-файла в ручную?

Answer (score 2):

Перезагрузиться пробовали? Изменение размера файла подкачки - после ребута...![alt text][1][Первая ссыль][2] в [гугле][3]...  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD1iF.png  [2]: http://netler.ru/ikt/windows7-swap-file.htm  [3]: https://www.google.by/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=ru&tbo=d&spell=1&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8+windows+7&sa=X&ei=pJcaUZHoHu364QTKloGoCA&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,bs.1,d.Yms&fp=e9a6c9a51a3d3ff6&ion=1&biw=1024&bih=656

Answer (score 1):

В настройках "Исходный" и "Максимальный" размеры файла подкачки должны быть установлены одинаково - 4096 Мбайт. Как я понял - это нужно, чтобы не было фрагментации файла подкачки (иначе лучше отдать его регулирование системе). Поэтому после желательно сделать дефрагментацию файла подкачки, и так его и оставить.

Answer (score 1):

Привет!
Я лично делаю так (и в ХР и в 7-ке):

- создаю отдельный раздел Гб На 5 (чтобы не надоедало сообщением об использовании пространства)
- убираю "наблюдать" с этого диска в "восстановлении системы" (нечего здесь наблюдать!)
- в настройках быстродействия ставлю на диск "C" - "без файла подкачки" (ну раз у меня подкачка уже будет в другом месте!). да, - оно что-то там ругается про "хотя бы 2 Мб" - ну и ладно, проехали.
- на вновь созданном разделе (букву даю обычно "S:") задаю размер файла подкачки (он же своппингх, `pagefile`...) 4096 - 4096. Иногда в 7-ке пишет, типа, "рекомендуемый размер - 4736" - шо это за смс-ка я без понятия. игнорируем-с.
- всё. ребут.
- удачи!